# PHP sessions and race conditions

Tags: php, session

The PHP [documenation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) for `session_write_close` says

> ...but as session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session at any time.

Could somebody please elaborate on what this means? Does this mean that the actual session store is locked for writing? If so and I'm using a custom session handler that writes to a SQL database, how do things change? Are all subsequent requests for that session completely blocked until the lock is released?

I ask because I'm using a custom session handler that uses a table in a MySQL database, and I think I might be encountering a race condition when more than one request comes in at a time for a session. If the first request reads the session from the table, and a second request comes in before the first finishes, will the second request get blocked until the first completely finishes or calls `session_write_close`? If not, would it be possible for the second to overwrite whatever the first had just written if it had read before the first had written?

Also, if the first request is aborted after reading the session but before it writes, is `session_write` still called?

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php#49630 there's no locking when you use a custom session handler.

Comment: if you use a database there is no lock

Comment: So I'll have to lock the table manually in my case?

Comment: If you don't data to be overwritten by a 2nd request while the first is still active then yes